# Entity Framework and SQL Server locking

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, transactions, locking

As far as I understand, the transactions used in SQL Server are locking the related tables. But the part that confuses me is does the `saveChanges()` method that we use in the Entity Framework implicitly lock the related table or just the related row?

My other question is, does a normal update query do any locking? Without using transactions.

Comment: Locking is integral to concurrency in databases. Every query in Sql Server by default starts an implicit transaction. The type, duration and escalation of locks depends on the isolation level; the default is `read comitted` but usually better concurrency can be obtained using `snapshot isolation` - which the the default for some other servers eg Oracle.

Comment: that is, locking occurs in every way. Well, do the saveChanges() method and a query that is not in the transaction lock the whole table or the related row?

Comment: The answer is "it depends" but normally, in a well designed database, if you are only updating one row then only that row should be locked. But there are other considerations. Rather than asking an abstract question, why not tell us what your are observing that has led you to ask this question?